# While statement repeats infinitely

Tags: php, html, if-statement, while-loop

I have a website where i need to use a while statement, but when i use it, it repeats the echo infinitely. Although it looks like i could make it work without while, that isnt so, this is a simplified version of a final product that will need while.

```
<?php 
$passlevel = '0';
while ($passlevel == '0')
{
    if(isset($_GET['box_1_color']))
    {
        $color=$_GET['box_1_color'];
        if($color == "#800080")
        {
            echo "you have passed step one.";
            $passlevel == '1';      
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "you didn't select purple.";
        }   
    }
    else echo "contact webmaster";
}
?>
```

Why is it echoing either contact webmaster or you didnt select purple an infinite number of times?

Comment: Actually, if you really indent like in your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/ef5a78af-47fa-468e-b919-16884eb9363e/view-source), then I can tell you why you get confused …

Comment: got messed up because of the formatting of 5 indents to show its code

Comment: but you saw what would be posted in the preview and didn't thought it would be necessary to fix the indentation? Also all the code in scope of the outmost if was indented with one tab ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you probably need to change:

```
$passlevel == '1';
```

to

```
$passlevel = '1';
```

The first is a comparison equals, not an assignment equals.

Second, if `$color` is not `#800080`, then the loop does not terminate and thus repeats forever as nothing in the loop causes the value to change.

I'm not entirely sure of the point of this loop in the first place.  It should work perfectly fine without the loop, however you've stated that your code is a simplified version of something more complicated that indeed needs a loop.  Perhaps you can elaborate.

Comment: Like my post says, there are other parts of the site that make it necessary to use a while statement here, several variables are dynamic and therefore will have a different while statement later on.

Comment: when i remove the extra =, nothing echoes

Comment: @ryno - I understand that.  I've tried to clarify what's going on, while acknowledging the fact that you have some reason for this loop which I don't fully understand.

Comment: @ryno - The extra equals on the assignment? (Line 11)

Comment: I compare what the color of background of a div that a user selects through the url and isset $_GET. My aim is to use while to simplify the code instead of having ten if statements inside each other (which was causing errors earlier). Im hoping to increase the value of passlevel upon each step then do another while statement for the next color.

Comment: The point is, if the value of `$passlevel` never changes in your `for` loop, the loop will go on forever.  Nothing in your originally posted code changes that variable, thus you get the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Doesnt $passlevel == '1'; which now is $passlevel = '1'; change the value to 1?

Comment: so now its just repeating the contact webmaster line, not the others. What could i change to make that line only show once?

Comment: @ryno - Yes, a single equals (assignment equals) will change the value of the variable, and return the new value.  A double equals will return a Boolean expression whether the two operands are equal to each other.

Comment: @ryno - Either get rid of the while loop, or change the value of `$passlevel` if the user did not select purple.

Comment: ill remove it if i can think of a work around. if not ill change the level. Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13572/discussion-between-ryno-and-mike-christensen)

Answer (score 4):

You're not providing any way out of the loop. If `$_GET['box_1_color']` isn't purple the first time through the loop, it can't possibly become anything else the second time through the loop, so it'll keep being the wrong color each and every time.

I'm not certain what you intended for this loop to accomplish. If you're trying to have the user enter a new value each time, you won't be able to do that with a loop in PHP. You'll have to regenerate the entire page (with an error message, presumably) and ask the visitor to submit the form again.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of "contact webmaster", you need to `break` out of the loop, either with the `break` expression or by setting your $passlevel to anything other than zero. A more serious real problem is revealed in @Mike Christensen's answer, though

Answer (score 1):

If `$_GET['box_1_color']` is not set, the variable `$passlevel` will never be changed.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
$passlevel = 0;
while ($passlevel == 0 || $passlevel == 2)
{
    if(isset($_GET['box_1_color']))
    {
        $color=$_GET['box_1_color'];
        if($color == "#800080")
        {
            echo "you have passed step one.";
            $passlevel = 1;      
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "you didn't select purple.".'try again.';
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        echo "contact webmaster";
        $passlevel = 2;
    }
}
?>
```

You need to define another passlevel for failure, to stop the while loop. Also, don't put any quotes around integers.

Comment: And who should the content of `$_GET` ever change?

Comment: Fixed. I didn't really understand the concept of your game.

Comment: I added some indentation to your answer. If the user selects another color than purple, he will still be stuck in the loop.